# conan search return only packages of latest recipe revision/hash

Tags: conan

For conan 1.45 doing conan search

```
conan search mypackage/1.0.1@user/channel -r dev-remote --revisions
Revisions for 'mypackage/1.0.1@user/channel' at remote 'dev-remote':
eb650b8e69461657d08a298e6f4f81f0 (2023-05-31 00:09:44 UTC)
52c9fc7da5009c0e11d4cddf9bff688e (2022-09-08 10:39:34 UTC
```

```
conan search mypackage/1.0.1@user/channel -r dev-remote
```

reveals only the packages from the `52c9fc7da5009c0e11d4cddf9bff688e` recipe revision, which are all `Outdated from recipe: True`.

Why is it not showing all packages from all recipe revisions (outdated and non outdated ones)?

When I do

```
conan search mypackage/1.0.1@user/channel#eb650b8e69461657d08a298e6f4f81f0  -r dev-remote
```

conan shows me the non outdated packages (because they are part of the latest recipe revision that I specified)

revisions are enabled on the client and on artifactory. Was this a bug in conan 1.45? I am stuck unfortunately with this version.

How can I use the conan search command to return only the non outdated packages?

The [outdated flag](https://github.com/conan-io/conan/blob/1.45.0/conans/client/conan_api.py#L987) doesn't seem to change anything, the conan search command I use always shows only the outdated packages.

Comment: The ``conan search`` lists the package binaries you ask for, if you don't specify a revision, it assumes latest, if you specify a revision it takes that revision. When using revisions, packages should never be outdated, because that is what revisions do, so it is not very clear what you mean, probably submit a ticket to https://github.com/conan-io/conan